# Is there a way, to change an action of a form two selections (two selects) after a button press?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm setting up a webpage for my IoT system, to be able to create If This Then That statements. I want to be able to choose from two selects. Then, after the button press, I want to be redirected to another page being /{{ value of first selection}}/{{ value of second selection }}/.

I have it working for one selection, there is a js function that is called when the first selection is changed and that changes the form action. I have no clue on how to change the code to also do this with the second selection, as I am not really fluent in js.

Html Template (if_create_start.html):

```
<form action="" method = "POST" id = "FORM_ID">
    <p>
        <select name="list_sensors_select" required onchange="changeAction(this)">
            <option disabeled selected>Choose a Sensor</option>
                {% for key, value in list_sensors.items() %}
                    <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value["nice_name"] }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <script>
            changeAction = function(select){
                document.getElementById("FORM_ID").action = select.value;
            }
        </script>
    </p>

    <p>
        <select name="until_select">
        <option selected value="none">Function Disabled</option>
        <option value="time">Amount of Time Passed</option>
        <option value="button">Button Pressed</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

webapp.py:

```
@app.route('/if/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def if_dash():
    with open('sensors.json') as json_file:
        list_sensors = json.load(json_file)

    return render_template("if_create_start.html", list_sensors=list_sensors)

@app.route('/if/<real_name>', methods = ['POST'])
def if_sensor(real_name):
    with open('sensors.json') as json_file:
        list_sensors = json.load(json_file)

    if not real_name in list_sensors:
        abort(404)

    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            result = request.form
            return render_template("result.html", result=result)
```

json file:

```
{
    "garage_door": {"nice_name": "Garage Door Sensor", "type": "float"},
    "sensor1": {"nice_name": "Sensor 1", "type": "float"},
    "sensor2": {"nice_name": "Sensor 2", "type": "time"}
}
```

So as I said, after the button press, I want to be routed to /if/{{ list_senors_select value }}/{{ until_select value }}/.
I guess that I need to modify the js script, but I don't know how. I would be thankful for any help.

I never know hom much info/script to provide, so if I provided too much/too little, feel free to contact me and I will reduce it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the action when either select1 OR select2 changes:

```html
<select id="select1" name="list_sensors_select" required onchange="changeAction()">
<select id="select2" name="until_select" onChange="changeAction()">
```

```js
function changeAction() {
    // Sensor
    var select1 = document.getElementById("select1");
    var val1 = select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value;
    // Until
    var select2 = document.getElementById("select2");
    var val2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].value;
    // Change form action
    document.getElementById("FORM_ID").action = "/" + val1 + "/" + val2;
}
```

Edit: You would also need to check if the `until_select` isn't none/disabled.